# Invalid api key when requesting for Google cloud Vision api in android app

Tags: android, api, key, google-cloud-platform

Hello I'm trying to test out the google cloud vision api for my android app.
I enabled the api and created an OAuth 2.0 client ID and I'm using the sample code 
from google: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-vision/blob/master/android/CloudVision/app/src/main/java/com/google/sample/cloudvision/MainActivity.java

and here is the json resonse:

```
{"code": 400,

"errors": [

{

"domain": "global",

"message": "API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key.",

"reason": "badRequest"

}

],

"message": "API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key.",

"status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"  }
```

I am pretty sure the api key provided is the one I am using.
What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the problem.The tutorial by google did not cover creating the api key. I realized I was using a service account key hence the issue.
On the platform one should choose create credentials then from the drop down menu choose create api key. Google should cover that in the tutorial.